# Compiling on Fedora with OptiX

Tags: cycles-render-engine, cuda

I run under Fedora 36 and NVCC complains about gcc being above version 11, it's a pain to install it and would prefer to just follow the advise in the error message:

`/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/crt/host_config.h:132:2: erreur: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 11 are not supported! The nvcc flag '-allow-unsupported-compiler' can be used to override this version check; however, using an unsupported host compiler may cause compilation failure or incorrect run time execution. Use at your own risk.`

I tried modifing intern/cycles/kernel/CMakeLists.txt, where the command line it formed, with no success.